# Error in GLM model

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, glm

I've been using R for a while but I'm trying to learn a bit of Python now. I am attempting to run a simple binomial glm classification with Kaggle's Titantic dataset. Here is the code for the model itself:

```
    formula = 'Survived ~ Pclass + Gender + AgeFill + Fare'
    glm = smf.glm(formula = formula, data = train_data, family = sm.families.Binomial()).fit()
```

But when I run the model I receive this error:

```
IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis 
(`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

I edited the model with pandas DataFrame but then converted things back to an numpy array. Everything in the model is a float and there are no missing values. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Answering this without an example of the data is going to be very difficult. Can you reduce the size of `train_data` and still reproduce this error? maybe try with a smaller formula? I'm guessing you are following [this example](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/glm_formula.html) Does following that example result in an error as well? If not the next step is figuring out what is different in your data, though without knowing what the data looks like I would just be guessing.

Comment: As I'm thinking about this more, what happens if you leave the dataframe as a dataframe and don't convert it to an array?

Comment: @johnchase Here are the first 5 rows of the array:
array([[  0.    ,   3.    ,   7.25  ,   1.    ,  22.    ],
[  1.    ,   1.    ,  71.2833,   0.    ,  38.    ],

       [  1.    ,   3.    ,   7.925 ,   0.    ,  26.    ],

       [  1.    ,   1.    ,  53.1   ,   0.    ,  35.    ],

       [  0.    ,   3.    ,   8.05  ,   1.    ,  35.    ]])

That example was the basic structure I was attempting to follow but I have not attempted to run the example myself. I may attempt that in a little bit to see if I get the same issue

Comment: @johnchase When I run it as a dataframe I receive a different error: [ValueError: For numerical factors, num_columns must be an int]. I found this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pystatsmodels/KcSzNqDxv-Q) of people who were having the same issue. I updated patsy but the issue still persisted so I assumed I needed to convert things back to an array.

Comment: The reason that the array is not working is because it does not contain keys. From the notes:
"data must define __getitem__ with the keys in the formula terms
args and kwargs are passed on to the model instantiation. E.g.,
a numpy structured or rec array, a dictionary, or a pandas DataFrame.
Basically statsmodels needs row and column names in order to be able to map the data to the formula." I would recommend leaving your data as a dataframe. I'm unsure of the other error, though there should be no reason why a pandas dataframe shouldn't work if the data is valid.

Comment: I had the same error: `[ValueError: For numerical factors, num_columns must be an int]` even after updating patsy to 0.4.1. A simple restart of iPython made the script run without any errors after.